# how to retrieve information from EntityCollection using linq queries?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I have some entities as

```
EntityCollection retrievedEntities =(EntityCollection)serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

from `retrievedEntities` i want to retrive a attribute value from a particular entity which has attribule value = to some value(`string` or `int` )

Can a single linq query do the trick ??

```
        var q = from p in retrieve.Entities
                where p.Attributes.Keys = "new_attribute1" && p.Attributes.Values = "avik"
                select p.Attributes.Values;
```

Comment: var entity = retrievedEntities.where(x=>x.attribute == somevalue).firstordefault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as suggested by @Frebin Francis

```
var q =retrieve.Entities.Where(x=>x.Attributes.Keys== "new_attribute1" && x.Attributes.Values = "avik").Select(x=>x.Attributes.Values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will stick with my plain and simple foreach loop  thank you

```
        foreach (var p in retrieve.Entities)
        {
           if(p["new_elementid"]=="some variable or constant ")
               temp = (int)p["new_elementid"];
        }
```